# Selected option of dropdown not changing after being set Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that is generated in C#

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", Model.States, new { id = "BTState" }, Model.GetDisabled("State"))
```

I noticed that after I select a different option, the selected value is not changing, even though it is displaying the option I selected. For example, when the page loads the value is "RI"; if I change it to "MA", the dropdown says "MA", but when I submit the form the value that is submitted is "RI" and when I inspect the dropdown in Chrome, I can see that "RI" is selected.

I thought maybe I could fix this by setting the selected option manually, so I wrote this:

```
$("select").on("change", function () {
    var state = $("option:selected", this).text();
    $("option", this).filter(function () {
        //may want to use $.trim in here
        return $(this).text() == state;
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

It seemed to be working; when I step through, 'state' is the option that I selected, and at the end of the method when I hover over 'this' and inspect the options, "MA" has "selected=true" and "RI" has "selected=false". However, when I inspect the select box, RI is still selected:

```
<option selected="selected" value="RI">RI</option>
```

Comment: try prop('selected', 'selected');

Comment: try `$(this).("option:selected", this).val();`

Comment: how do you code your form, maybe there is something wrong?